# If I'm using cache why it's necessary to use CSS sprites and bundle static resources

Tags: performance, caching, minify, ccsprite, jsmin

I'm making big effort in order to get better performance for web application that I developing.

My question is: If I'm already using cache for images, JS's, CSS's and other static resources why it's necessary to use CSS sprites, JS/CSS bundle, JS/CSS minify and etc. if after first time loading everything is cached?

I would like to emphasis this is about web application that used in inner network and I would like to know if the get better performance action's effects after the static resources was cached.